# Is this possible to know user give feedback in SKStoreReviewController or user click submit button or not now button in SKStoreReview

Tags: swift, skstorereviewcontroller

Is there is any delegate or way to know user has submit his review on SKStoreReview , i want to show and hide **custom View** on **submit** and **not now button**,  if user submits his review then don't want to show custom view or user select not now button then show custom view is there is any delegate or way to handle this condition in SKStoreReview API, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

no delegate for this, you can use this [library](https://github.com/takecian/SwiftRater) with this function, at least you will know if user clicked on rate button.

```
func rateButtonDidClick(sender: UIButton) {
    // do something ..

    SwiftRater.rateApp(host: self)
}
```